# rvalue reference — I'm losing the value

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I'm a bit confused about the rvalue reference so I have tried the following code:

```c++
std::vector<char> stringToChar(std::string& str)
{
    std::vector<char> rep(str.begin(), str.end());
    return rep;
}

std::vector<char>& cryptPassword(std::vector<char>&& password)
{
    // static const char _key = 56; //crypt password
    // for (char &c : password)
    //   c = c ^ _key;
    return (password);
}

std::vector<char>& stringToPassword(std::string& str)
{
    return cryptPassword(stringToChar(str));
}
```

In the first case I'm getting the correct output, but I the second case I'm getting garbage.

```c++
std::string str("Hello");
std::vector<char> tmp = cryptPassword(stringToChar(str));

//correct output
for (char c : tmp)
   std::cout << c;
std::cout << std::endl;

//garbage
tmp = stringToPassword(str);
for (char c : tmp)
   std::cout << c;
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: `stringToChar` and `stringToPassword` should take a const reference , since they don't modify their argument. (Doing this would have thrown up compiler errors to alert you to the problem, instead of running and producing garbage for the second snippet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `stringToChar(str)` is an rvalue that will bind to the rvalue reference taken by `cryptPassword()`. When returning `password` the vector is copied and bound to the reference (`cryptPassword()` returns an lvalue reference). The problem is that the return value is a temporary copy that has since died after the call to `temp = stringToPassword()`. Using it is Undefined Behavior.

Instead of returning a reference, return by value and `std::move()` `password` out:

```c++
std::vector<char> cryptPassword(std::vector<char>&& password)
{
    // ...  
    return std::move(password);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'm starting to understand.
I will do some more test to understand exactly how it work.

Comment: Making the above change does not make the code compile. I get the following error "error: non-const lvalue reference to type
      'vector<[...]>' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'vector<[...]>'"

Comment: @Rush According to the OP the code compiled in the first place but the problem was that he was getting a garbage output.

Comment: @Rush I see, thanks. Are you sure you got rid of the reference from the return type?

Comment: Yes, I did. I copy pasted it from here. Do I have to remove the reference from "stringToPassword" function as well? That works for me

Comment: @Rush Yes because the return value is a temporary its return type shouldn't be a reference.

Comment: Ok, it would be helpful if you could edit the code above for that part as well.

Comment: @Rush I did. I said to return by value. :)

Comment: Should be `return password;` . `std::move` has no effect whatsoever here (it means `static_cast<T&&>`, but you already have an rvalue reference.)

Comment: @MattMcNabb `password`'s type is an rvalue reference but it will still be used as an lvalue unless `std::move()` is called.

Comment: @0x499602D2 no it won't. What do you think `std::move` does? It is just a wrapper for `static_cast` to an rvalue reference.

Comment: In this code the return value is move-constructed from `password`, whether or not you did `std::move`

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm not saying `std::move` *moves*, I know it doesn't. It's that `password` is an lvalue while being returned and lvalues cannot bind to rvalue references. A copy will be made instead ([see this example](http://rextester.com/AAYGBW63558)). So we cast to an rvalue so the move constructor can be used.

Comment: @0x499602D2 OK, I can't explain your example, I don't see why `X(X const &)` is a better match than `X(X&&)` for argument of type `X&&`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Simple. `x` is an lvalue because it has a name. So it will be treated like an lvalue unless otherwise specified. That's also why we call `std::forward` on universal references.

Comment: so parameter `X&&` is actually the same as `X const &` ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb No, but an lvalue can bind to `X const&` unlike `X&&`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 OK , I'm completely lost. It seems as crazy as making `void f(int x) { int y = x; }` be an error unless you wrote `int y = (int)x;` . maybe I should stick to BASIC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58560/discussion-between-0x499602d2-and-matt-mcnabb).